# How to request to by the Firefox adding on

Tags: firefox-addon

I am troubled without understanding the method of the outside request by the Firefox adding on.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but it sounds like XmlHttpRequest. Here's an example: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=102637&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firefox Addons Development Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_dev_guide) should answer your questions about Firefox add-ons. Also see the [Mozilla Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions) documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not very clear, but if you are looking for something like an HTTPRequest in a Firefox Addon, the following code snippet may help you.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.sitetorequest.com",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   Your Code here...
  }
 }

xmlhttp.send(null)
```

Comment: Im main.js this gives me a `XMLHttpRequest is not defined` message